# How to prevent a ComboBox from firing another ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event when filling it

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ado.net, selectedindexchanged

So, basically I'm using a `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event to fill 5 more `ComboBox`s wich each have their own `SelectedIndexChanged` event as well.

The problem is that when the first `SelectedIndexChanged` event fires to fill the rest.. it also fires the other `ComboBox`es' `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

In order to prevent that, I have found a solution using the event `SelectionChangeCommited` on the rest of the `ComboBox`es.

But now, that event (unlike `SelectedIndexChanged`) doesn't fire on the first click on the item of the `ComboBox`... you need to select the item two or three times before it does.

So, my question is: is there any way to fix these problems?

Comment: If the child combobox `SelectedIndex` property changes to -1 when the parent `selectionChanged` fires you could parse out when to take action.  I think when nothing is selected the `SelectedIndex` goes to -1.  So essentially ignore` Selectedindex = -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make local variable and set it for the time the `SelectedIndexChanged` should be ignored

```
protected bool ignoreSelectedIndexChanged = false;

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ignoreSelectedIndexChanged) { return; }

    //rest of code
}
```

it seems to me more explicit than fiddling with the events.

In the main `ComboBox` use something like:

```
private void comboBoxMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    try
    {
        ignoreSelectedIndexChanged = true;

        //comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        //comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 2;
        //comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 3;
        //...

    }
    finally
    {
        ignoreSelectedIndexChanged = false;
    }
}
```

`SelectionChangedCommited` may be another way how to do it. But it is fired only when user does the selection, what may be limiting for some cases. And there were dome bugs of not firing when it should. I personally avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in this case should I just forget about the SelectionChangedCommited event or will the SelectedIndexChanged event work ?

Comment: @watchDogMan I added more explanation if it helps.

Comment: It worked very well, Thanks again, easy solution, never thought of it tho (y)

Answer (score 1):

In code, before you 'fill' the secondary comboboxes, unsubscribe from their SelectedIndexChanged event, then re-subscribe when the 'fill' code has run

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do find it intresting, Could you please give me an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag, for example
in case you only have 2 combo boxes

```
int flag =0;

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(flag)
    {
       case 0:
           flag = 1;
       break;

       case 1:
           // your code here
           // after it you should set flag = 0
       break;

       default:
       break;
    }

}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    switch(flag)
    {
       case 0:
           flag = 2;
       break;

       case 2:
           // your code here
           // after it you should set flag = 0
       break;

       default:
       break;
    }        
}
```

and just like that depending on the number of comboboxes you're using.